# MACD pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to set up an indicator (below) to give an alert when the MACD cross over occurs at a much higher level than the standard zero line. My idea is to only consider the trade when the MACD crossover occurs way above or below the zero line and not just very close to the zero line itself.

Appreciate if someone can help as the one below is not working.

```
// MACD current timeframe
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

crossoverBull = ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine) and signalLine < -0.02
crossoverBear = ta.crossunder(macdLine, signalLine) and signalLine > 0.02
```